# Add a custom icon to embedded google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm adding maps to a website dynamically, finding the lat and lng by using google's geocoding service. I'd like to put a marker on the position returned by the geocoding service, on top of that, I'd like the marker to be a custom image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the GIcon class. Please take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Custom_Icons

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using V3 of the API's, and this didn't quite work. But it sent me in the right direction for looking, found the same thing for V3: [V3 Overlays: Markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers).
So, thanks!